# How can I get this gsub function to work for me?

Tags: r

Very new to R, and am learning a lot on the fly by experimenting with building a model. I have tried searching for the solution but have not found anything.

I have a dataframe named HPPH that looks like this. I am trying to reformat it to a number. **Ex: 39' 11" changed to 39.11**

```
      player_name      PH        
  <chr>            <chr>     
1 Chad Campbell    "39' 11\""
2 Charl Schwartzel "39' 7\"" 
3 Ángel Cabrera    "39' 6\"" 
4 Vaughn Taylor    "39' 4\"" 
5 Stephen Ames     "39' 4\""
```

When I use `gsub("' ", ".", HPPH$PH)` I get this result:

```
> gsub("' ", ".", HPPH$PH)
 [1] "39.11\"" "39.7\""  "39.6\""  "39.4\""  "39.4\""  "39.1\""  "39.1\""  "39.0\""  "38.10\"" "38.4\""  "40.7\"" 
[12] "38.2\""  "38.1\""  "38.1\""  "37.7\""  "37.4\""  "37.2\""  "37.1\""  "37.0\""  "36.11\"" "36.9\""  "36.8\"" 
[23] "38.2\""  "36.5\""  "40.9\""  "40.10\"" "48.11\"" "40.10\"" "47.3\""  "45.11\"" "45.10\"" "45.7\""  "45.5\"" 
[34] "44.7\""  "43.8\""  "43.1\""  "42.10\"" "41.6\""  "40.10\"" "46.3\""  "36.4\""  "36.2\""  "36.0\""  "29.8\"" 
[45] "29.10\"" "29.10\"" "35.10\"" "35.9\""  "35.7\""  "35.6\""  "35.5\""  "35.5\""  "35.2\""  "35.2\""  "35.0\"" 
[56] "34.8\""  "34.8\""  "34.4\""  "34.0\""  "33.9\""  "33.6\""  "33.5\""  "33.1\""  "33.0\""  "31.10\"" "31.5\"" 
[67] "31.3\""  "31.0\""  "30.11\""
```

So it seems as if it's doing what it is supposed to but when I view HPPH, it is not changing anything.

```
> head(HPPH)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  player_name      PH        
  <chr>            <chr>     
1 Chad Campbell    "39' 11\""
2 Charl Schwartzel "39' 7\"" 
3 Ángel Cabrera    "39' 6\"" 
4 Vaughn Taylor    "39' 4\"" 
5 Stephen Ames     "39' 4\"" 
6 David Toms       "39' 1\""
```

If I assign it with `HPPH$PH <- gsub("' ", ".", HPPH$PH)`it gets turned into a value and when I use View(HPPH) it now shows up as this.

[image: HPPH]

Comment: the library `stringr` is part of the tidyverse and is all about strings for future reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to assign it to the object

```
HPPH$PH <- gsub("' ", ".", HPPH$PH)
```

Comment: I should have been more specific. I added more details into the original post. When I do that it changes into a value instead of data in the environment. See image above.

Comment: @KarsenMitsche Please check the `str(HPPH)` instead of `View`

Comment: This is what I get: str(HPPH)
 chr [1:69] "39.11\"" "39.7\"" "39.6\"" "39.4\"" "39.4\"" "39.1\"" "39.1\"" "39.0\"" "38.10\"" "38.4\"" "40.7\"" ...

Comment: YOu want the numeric part only? then, remove the double quote with `gsub('"', '', HPPH$PH)`

Comment: no I want to keep it as a data frame. With the player name and then the value in the column next to it as shown in the original data frame above. When I use the gsub function, it is no longer a dataframe and I lose the player names/column headers, etc..

Comment: @KarsenMitsche What happens when you do `HPPH$PH <-`, (it is assigning to that column)

Comment: @KarsenMitsche that looks like a `data.frame` to me

Comment: look at the first dataframe I posted. It includes the players name and the column header is PH not V1. When I use the gsub function it is getting rid of the player name column. So it is not working properly, this is what I’m trying to say. I can not access the dataframe by referencing it after using the gsub function. Ex HPPH$PH does not exist after using the gsub function. In my environment it is no longer an accessible dataframe after using the function as well.

Comment: @KarsenMitsche can you edit your post with a dput of a small example. i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(HPPH)))`

Comment: This is what I get: Error in UseMethod("droplevels") : 
  no applicable method for 'droplevels' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: @KarsenMitsche that is strange, can you do `dput(head(HPPH))`

Comment: > dput(head(HPPH))
c("39.11\"", "39.7\"", "39.6\"", "39.4\"", "39.4\"", "39.1\""
)

Comment: @KarsenMitsche it is not a data.frame as per the dput.  It is a vector.  Please check your original dataset with `str(HPPH)` and this one

Comment: You may have accidentally assigned the `gsub` to `HPPH<-` instead of `HPPH$PH`

Comment: That was exactly the issue. Crazy how you can sometimes miss something so simple and obvious. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just did that. That was exactly the issue. Crazy how you can sometimes miss something so simple and obvious. Thanks for your help!

Comment: One more quick question. How would I change the " at the end to nothing so that it shows as just a number. R isn't understanding the reference if I do """. And can I do this all in one function?

Comment: You can remove the `"` with `gsub('"', "", HPPH$PH)`

Comment: Thanks. Can I do both in one function or does it have to be two separately?

Comment: @KarsenMitsche in the first case you are replacing with `.`, so, it can be done separately